# Error in as.environment(pos) : no item called "dataset" on the search list

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to give selectInput in ui - Rshiny

```
selectInput('dataset',label = 'Dataset',choices = ls('package:datasets'))
```

but I am getting this error :
Error in as.environment(pos) :    no item called "package:dataset" on the search list

can someone help ?

Comment: The error is coming from the ‘ls’ function. The quoted text is not being interpreted as something R can find. I’m wondering if ‘dataset’ is being spelled wrong? “datasets”? Perhaps?

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/datasets/html/00Index.html